# Terraform: how to pass output variables from the child module to the caller module

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-aws

The real example is very complicated, I tried to simplify it:

```
variable "input" {
    type = string
    default  "In Xanadu did Khubla Khan"
}

module "child" {
    source = "./child
    input = var.input
}

output "output" {
    value = module.child.output
}
```

Now the child module

```
variable "input" {
    type = string
}

output "output" {
    value = "${var.input} a stately pleasure dome decree"
}
```

As result I'm getting

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on output.tf line 122, in output "output":
│  122:   value       =  module.child.output
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.child is a object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "output".
```

UPDATE: I used here an abstract example with variable names like "input" and "output" and copied the error message from the real terraform script referencing the variable "aws_s3_cxrossaccount_iam_role_arn". This was obviously confusing for some of the readers of this note. So I replaced the real name in the error message by the name "output" I used in this example.

Well of course the error message was taken from a real script, but I expect, that with my example above I would get something alike

I already googled this issue but did not get any clues.
Terraform provider version is

```
C:\Databricks\dbx_tpch> terraform -version
Terraform v1.2.2
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks v1.14.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.62.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.4.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.9.1

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.4.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

Of course I can upgrade, but I don't think, that it would help anyway

Comment: The error message states that the module does not contain an output with that name. Is that accurate?

Comment: No, that is not accurate.   1) As you may see from the example I posted here - each variable, I refer in the main directory is defined as output in the child directory. 2) The message in fact says "module.workspace is a object, known only after apply"  first and only them "This object does not have an attribute named".

Comment: by any chance is it possible that you are creating an output `aws_s3_cxrossaccount_iam_role_arn` in your root module and then using child module {workspace} for its value? The error message totally depends on the structure. it would be helpful to answer if you share the dir structure for the child, and root modules.

Comment: this is not a direct answer but it at least gives you a basic structure of passing output from one module to another one.
https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/azure/how_to_get_value_from_modules_in_another_module

Comment: Have you tried applying exactly the configuration you shared in your question? Did that return the same error as you saw with your real configuration?

Comment: Hi, @MartinAtkins - the issue is - I upgraded Terraform    terraform version
Terraform v1.4.4
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks v1.14.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.62.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.5.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.9.1     -

Answer (score 0):

1. Workaround
   instead of re-defining every output variable from the child module in the root module, refer to the whole child module

```
output "single_child_output" {
    description = "Do not use it"
    value = module.child.child_output
}

output "all_child_outputs" {
    description = "use this instead"
    value = module.child
}
```

as result you will get a map

Outputs:

```
all_child_outputs = {
     "variable1" = "value1"
     "variable2" = "value2"
     "variable3" = "value3"
}
```

Iportant - this workaround worked even before I upgraded terraform

2. Solution ?

However, it happened, that I on one step of my troubleshooting upgraded the terraform itself

```
dbx_tpch> terraform version
Terraform v1.4.4
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks v1.14.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.62.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.5.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.9.1
```

The error is gone and I can use both variants from above  - address a single output variable in a child module or the whole output block. Both works.
IMHO addressing the whole block is sometimes easier, but if you want use the output from "terraform output"  as input for some scripts - it may be better to address by the single variable.